# Complete Boolean Lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, integer-lattices

What is the formal definition of Complete Boolean lattice $Q_n$? What would be an example for $n=4$, i.e. $Q_4$?

Comment: Some people probably use the notation $Q_n$ for the lattice of subsets of an $n$-element set (whose Hasse diagram looks like an $n$-dimensional cube). Some people might use this notation for the free Boolean lattice on $n$ generators. Some people (including me) don't use this notation at all.